# Unitary rotation of spin states

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, unitarity

> Consider the $2j+1$-dimensional Hilbert space spanned by the spin states
>   $$\left|j,-j\right>,\left|j,-j+1\right>,\ldots,\left|j,j-1\right>,\left|j,j\right>$$
>   where $\hbar m$ and $\hbar^2j(j+1)$ are the eigenvalues of $J_3$ and $J^2$ respectively.
>
> For a fixed $m,m'\in\{-j,\ldots,j\}$ is it always possible to construct a unitary operator $U$ such that $U\left|j,m\right> = \left|j,m'\right>$?

I believe the answer is yes. It is easiest to work in the matrix representation, i.e., associate $\left|j,m\right> = e_{m+j+1}$ for each $m$, where $e_{i}$ is the $i$'th standard basis vector in $\mathbb{R}^{2j+1}$. Now define $U$ by it's matrix elements as follows:
\begin{align}
&U_{m,m'} = U_{m',m} = 1, \\
&U_{ii} = 1 \text{ for all $i\neq m,m'$}, \\
&U_{ij} = 0 \text{ otherwise.}
\end{align}

For example, if we work with a spin-$\frac{3}{2}$ system and we want to construct a unitary operator that maps $\left|\frac{3}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right>\mapsto\left|\frac{3}{2},\frac{3}{2}\right>$, our matrix would read
$$U = \begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1 \\ 0&0&1&0 \\0&1&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$
Clearly this will do the job.

Now, our definition is clearly symmetric and hence being real, is also Hermitian. Clearly, we also have that $U^2 = I$, so $U=U^{-1}$. Altogether we have
$U^{-1} = U = U^\dagger$, and so, $U$ is unitary.

It seems that we have accomplished the task at hand relatively easily. In fact, any operator that swaps the desired basis states and permutes the others with an order-2 permutation will be unitary and do the job. So, there seems to be many choices of this unitary operator. It almost feels too easy. I am wondering if anyone notices any subtle (or even glaring) mistakes / unjustified assumptions I have made? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it is in fact possible to construct matrices that take one basis vector to another in all finite-dimensional complex vector spaces. Given such a space with dimension $n$, it is not difficult to see that set of $n\times n$ permutation matrices satisfies the criteria. This is ultimately true because all finite-dimensional vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ with the same dimension are isomorphic. Subtitles only arise when one considers infinite-dimensional spaces.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that it was fully independent of the physical interpretation pretty quickly, but I decided to include it anyway because that's how I came across it in the first place. As ZeroTheHero pointed out, perhaps the question is geared more towards application of SU(2) operations (henc the physical properties of the system are more relavent) and I interpreted it too generally.

Answer (score 2):

You have of course set up things in a way that is completely independent of the $SU(2)$ structure of the Hilbert space: you approach is valid for an $d\times d$ Hilbert space and has nothing to do with spin.  As a result the matrices you obtain are NOT spin matrices, and are not related to $SU(2)$ rotations of spin states.

It is not clear if "unitary rotation" refers to just a unitary or an $SU(2)$ rotation matrix of appropriate dimension.  The $SU(2)$ rotations matrices are elements not only $(2j+1)\times (2j+1)$ unitary matrices but also elements of $SU(2)$.

In the example you give, the $4\times 4$ rotations matrices are of the form 
$e^{-im\alpha} d^{3/2}_{m,m'}(\beta)e^{-im'\gamma}$ with 
\begin{align}
&d^{3/2}_{mm'}(\beta)=\\
&
\left(
{\scriptsize
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \cos ^3\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & -\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} \csc \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin ^2(\beta ) & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\beta
   }{2}\right) \sin (\beta ) & -\sin ^3\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \\
 \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} \csc \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin ^2(\beta ) & \frac{1}{2} \cos \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) (3 \cos (\beta )-1) & -\frac{1}{2} (3 \cos
   (\beta )+1) \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin (\beta ) \\
 \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin (\beta ) & \frac{1}{2} (3 \cos (\beta )+1) \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \cos
   \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) (3 \cos (\beta )-1) & -\frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} \csc \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin ^2(\beta ) \\
 \sin ^3\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) & \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{3} \sin \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right) \sin (\beta ) & \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{3} \csc \left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)
   \sin ^2(\beta ) & \cos ^3\left(\frac{\beta }{2}\right)
\end{array}
}
\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}

Note that if you restrict to $SU(2)$ matrices then it is NOT always possible to a $d\times 2$ rotation matrix that will take $\vert jm\rangle$ to a single $\vert jm'\rangle$.  In addition there is no $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ angles that will transform (1) into the $U$ matrix you provide.